# per-record timeline consistency vs. monotonic writes

Tags: terminology, distributed-systems

It seems to me that the *per-record timeline consistency* as defined by Cooper et al. in "PNUTS: Yahoo!’s Hosted Data Serving Platform" mimics the (older?) definition of *monotonic writes*. From the paper:

> per-record timeline consistency: all replicas of a given record apply
>   all updates to the record in the same order.

This is quite similar to [a definition for monotonic writes](http://regal.csep.umflint.edu/~swturner/Classes/csc577/Online/Chapter06/img26.html):

> A write operation by a process on data item x is completed before any
>   successive write operation on x by the same process.

Can I conclude that those things are the same, or is there a difference that I misunderstand? Note that the link above also mentions possible copies of data item `x`, so monotonic write includes replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure these two concepts are really comparable.

*monotonic writes* is a client based consistency model. It defines what a process sees.

*per-record timeline consistency* strikes me as a memory based model. It doesn't even mention what a client sees or does.

So I would say they are not same or even comparable.